# Stuck in starting meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, digital-ocean

This is really frustrating me. I have a DO VPS with ubuntu 14.04 (64) installed.

I installed VestaCP as control panel on that and have hosted some PHP based personal project.

I also installed meteor on it but never used, now when I am trying to create a project and run it ('meteor create rt' then 'cd rt' then 'meteor')

It is giving the following error :
[[[[[ /home/admin/code/rt ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
Unexpected mongo exit code 1. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 1. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 1. Restarting.
Can't start Mongo server.
root@RD:/home/admin/code/rt#

Could anyone please help? Please ask me for more informations if required.

**** EDIT ****

I created a fresh DigitalOcean server and it is giving the same error on that. Some issue with Digital Ocean? File System of Digital Ocean? I am confused. I am trying it on different flavours of Linux and same result. All are fresh linux installations.

Comment: you'll need to dig a little deeper for us to help you. So far you are just saying you did exactly as instructed in terms of installing meteor and creating a project. Clearly something didn't quite work as intended, because 14.04 is well supported, so reproducing your error is near impossible. reinstall meteor?

Comment: tried removing meteor and reinstalling it. And a very strange thing : I have 6 digitalocean.com servers and two of them are giving same errors after I install meteor and run. Both run apache. Any clue?

Comment: will anyone tell me why it was downvoted?

Comment: It seems you are running as root, is that correct? What exactly are you doing to install meteor? Just running `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`?

Comment: Yes, @TimC, I am running as root and doing exactly as you stated. Should I be doing something else?

Comment: There are a few known issues running as root. Can you try running as a user account?

Comment: @TimC tried running as an user. Did not help. This is happening on all digitalocean servers I use. Even on the new ones which I create.

Comment: Hi Kumar, what is the filesystem about, you have created your meteor project in? Is some linked like NFS or something else? Just try it once at /tmp to create a new sample.

Comment: A lot of people deploy to DigitalOcean servers with meteor... So I somehow doubt this is a DigitalOcean specific issue. What error do you get when you run `meteor mongo`?

Comment: @TimC meteor mongo would work only when the app is running. right?

Comment: @TomFreudenberg I tried at /tmp. Same issue persists. And filesystem is not NFS.

Comment: Yes sorry you are right, the server must be started. As a further test, to see if we can isolate the problem to Mongo, can do run the following in your meteor applications directory: `MONGO_URL=mongodb://nowhere meteor`

Comment: OMG! @TimC what did you do? It is working. How did this happen?

Comment: It tells us that your mongo install is a mess. Basically right now you are running with no Mongo. We didn't really fix anything, we just removed something and narrowed it down. I will add an answer to help.

Comment: So this means, that on every server i create and run `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh` goes into mess automatically? Something to do with root? filesystems?

Comment: @KumarRavi please see my answer I started  and show us the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got the solution. Posting it here for others.

This was the problem as a few environment variables which mongodb looks for while starting was not set 
Set the variables `LC_ALL` and `LANG` and it works fine (mostly setting `LC_ALL` will do)

first, type `locale` command and see the output, you will see that it will say something about LC_ALL not set.

Now, add these two lines in `/etc/environment` and it worked.

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

This solution is for Ubuntu 12.04 +

Other variants may require similar work.

Comment: great! I saw that error also in other questions. Gracefully you've found it too!

Answer (score 1):

Unexpected mongo exit code 1 is still an uncaught exception as far as i think.

You can try by updating your c/c++ compilers uptodate. Have a look [here](http://manzzup.blogspot.in/2014/12/error-running-meteor-unexpected-mongo.html). 
It says :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.6
sudo apt-get install g++-4.6
```

All the best!

Comment: Hi Jackson, I went trough this post already and tried it. The problem still persists.

Comment: You are saying that you tried it on most other flavors of Linux as well? Did you try `meteor rest`

Answer (score 1):

So we have narrowed the issue down to meteor's mongo installation on your box (though I think we were pretty sure of this all along). Let's attempt to debug that a bit. The way I have done this in the past is to try to open meteor's mongo with the mongod provided by meteor. You will perform these procedures without running the meteor server. This should give you the warning that is causing Mongo to exit. First you need to find this. In my instance installed on Mint (which should be similar to Ubuntu) it is at:

`~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/mongodb/bin/mongod`

You can look at that location on your Ubuntu box or you can run something like this to get the location:

`find ~/.meteor/ -name mongod`

Once you find the location then go to the directory of your meteor project you are attempting to run and in that directory you should find this location:

`<your meteor project>/.meteor/local`

`cd` into that directory and run the following command:

`~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/mongodb/bin/mongod --dbpath ./`

From there you can analyze the output (or update the question so we can see the output) and this should show you the mongo error you are receiving on startup and allow you to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issues trying to start a meteor app and exactly the mongodb server is being terminated in an unexpectly manner. Generally the virtual linux server from some dealers like the one you mentioned are coming without a **swap** partition (check in **/etc/fstab** file) so if you have not enough memory to allocate MongoDB server then meteor app can't be started. You can create a [swap partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2208/79050) or instal [swapspace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134258/dynamically-growing-swap-file-on-debian/134261)

```
sudo apt-get install swapspace
```

After that I was able to start the meteor app... Just be patient as swap memory is not as faster as RAM.

Comment: I already have a swap and it's working. Saw it using the `free` command.

Answer (score 0):

*Since due some "smart" StackExchange policy I cannot up-vote or comment to working solution...)*

Quoted answer works also on Digital Ocean on CentOS 7 x64 vmlinuz-3.10.0-123.8.1.el7.x86_64

> first, type locale command and see the output, you will see that it will say something about LC_ALL not set.
>
> Now, add these two lines in **/etc/environment** and it worked.

I changed the locale setting to match my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed on my Debian 8 with the following bash command, (use sudo if needed)

```
localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
```